# for-each for each descendant

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to build below logic with xslt 2.0/1.0:

1. for-each `*[@name=summary]` go to the parent and look for all descendant `<info>` elements (except `@name=summary`)
2. for-each `info/@id` access the document uri for `@id`. And print the `<name>` element from the xml document.
3. if `@name=summary` and `@level=top`, do not process `<info>` with `@duplicate=yes`

XML

```html
<map>
   <info id="a.xml" level="top" name="summary"/>
   <map id="b.xml">
      <info id="c.xml" name="summary">
         <info id="1.xml"/>
         <info id="2.xml"/>
      </info>
   </map>
   <map id="d.xml">
      <info id="e.xml" name="summary">
         <info id="1.xml" duplicate="yes"/>
         <info id="4.xml"/>
         <info id="2.xml" duplicate="yes"/>
      </info>
   </map>
   <map id="f.xml">
      <info id="g.xml" name="summary">
         <info id="2.xml" duplicate="yes"/>
         <info id="1.xml" duplicate="yes"/>
         <info id="5.xml"/>
      </info>
   </map>
   <info id="h.xml" level="top" name="summary"/>
</map>
```

Output

```html
<result>
    <summary id="a.xml" level="top">
        <info id="1.xml">one</info>
        <info id="2.xml">two</info>
        <info id="4.xml">four</info>
        <info id="5.xml">five</info>
    </summary>
    <summary id="c.xml">
        <info id="1.xml">one</info>
        <info id="2.xml">two</info>
    </summary>
    <summary id="e.xml">
        <info id="1.xml">one</info>
        <info id="4.xml">four</info>
        <info id="2.xml">two</info>
    </summary>
    <summary id="g.xml">
        <info id="2.xml">two</info>
        <info id="1.xml">one</info>
        <info id="5.xml">five</info>
    </summary>
    <summary id="h" level="top">
        <info id="1.xml">one</info>
        <info id="2.xml">two</info>
        <info id="4.xml">four</info>
        <info id="5.xml">five</info>
    </summary>
</result>
```

1.xml, 2.xml, 4.xml, 5.xml, a.xml, b.xml... having similar structure (see comment below)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
    <name>one</name>
    <!-- 2.xml <name>two</name>, 4.xml <name>four</name>, 5.xml <name>five</name>, a.xml <name>a</name> ......    -->
</input>
```

Here is my xslt which does not give correct output:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="this" select="/"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[@name = 'summary']">
    <summary>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@level"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@name"></xsl:copy-of>
        <xsl:call-template name="createsummary"/>
    </summary>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="createsummary">
    <xsl:for-each select="../descendant::*">
        <xsl:for-each select="doc(resolve-uri(@id, document-uri($this)))/*">
            <xsl:if test="*[name() = 'name']">
                <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to set up the directory structure but the right `info` elements are found by

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="this" select="/"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@name = 'summary']">
        <summary>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@level"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@name"></xsl:copy-of>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="create-summary"/>
        </summary>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@name = 'summary' and @level = 'top']" mode="create-summary">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../descendant::info[not(@name = 'summary') and not(@duplicate = 'yes')] except ." mode="summary"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@name = 'summary' and not(@level = 'top')]" mode="create-summary">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../descendant::info[not(@name = 'summary')] except ." mode="summary"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="info" mode="summary">
        <info id="{@id}"></info>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

meaning the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <summary id="a.xml" level="top" name="summary">
      <info id="1.xml"/>
      <info id="2.xml"/>
      <info id="4.xml"/>
      <info id="5.xml"/>
   </summary>
   <summary id="c.xml" name="summary">
      <info id="1.xml"/>
      <info id="2.xml"/>
   </summary>
   <summary id="e.xml" name="summary">
      <info id="1.xml"/>
      <info id="4.xml"/>
      <info id="2.xml"/>
   </summary>
   <summary id="g.xml" name="summary">
      <info id="2.xml"/>
      <info id="1.xml"/>
      <info id="5.xml"/>
   </summary>
   <summary id="h.xml" level="top" name="summary">
      <info id="1.xml"/>
      <info id="2.xml"/>
      <info id="4.xml"/>
      <info id="5.xml"/>
   </summary>
</result>
```

So with the additional files you could change the template

```
    <xsl:template match="info" mode="summary">
        <info id="{@id}"></info>
    </xsl:template>
```

to

```
    <xsl:template match="info" mode="summary">
        <info id="{@id}">
           <xsl:value-of select="doc(resolve-uri(@id, document-uri($this)))/*/name"/>
        </info>
    </xsl:template>
```

and you should get what you want.